# Linking nodes in a D3.js Force Layout from multiple different JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working with a nested JSON feed to create a Force Directed graph with D3.js.

My current code looks for an child arrays named 'children'. And displays all items in those arrays as nodes. This has worked for a while and I've been happy.

But I now need to add a few more child arrays per item.

So my JSON structure would be similar to the following:

```
{  
   "structure":[  
      {  
         "name":"Grandfather",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "name":"Father 1",
               "son":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"Son"
                  }
               ],
               "daughter":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"Daughter"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "name":"Father 2",
               "son":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"Son"
                  }
               ],
               "daughter":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"Daughter"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

One of the things I'd like to achieve by doing this is to give nodes from different arrays separate styling.

And this is an image of the type of graph I'm looking to create.

[image]

Here is the D3.js code that I currently use. This works when there is only one child array named children.

```
var w = 1000,
    h = 800,
    radius = 10,
    node,
    link,
    root,
    title;

 var jsonURL = 'assets/scripts/nodes.json'

d3.json(jsonURL, function(json) {
    root = json.words[0]; //set root node
    root.fixed = true;
    root.x = w / 2;
    root.y = h / 2 - 80;
    update();
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function(d) { return -500; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 200 : 120; })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


function update() {
    var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

    // Update the links…
    link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update the nodes…
    node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .style("fill", "red")

    node.transition()
        .attr("r", radius);

    // Enter any new nodes.
    node.enter()
        .append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("fill", "red")
        .call(force.drag);

    // Exit any old nodes.
    node.exit().remove();

}

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + recurse(v); }, 0);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
        return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;

}
```

As I understand it, the recursive function is what I need to change to look at multiple arrays instead of just the children.

But then I also need to link these new nodes to their parents nodes.

If anyone has any ideas on how I would go about doing this. I would be most grateful.